# Identifying the limit of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, partial-differential-equations

Let $f(x,t)$ and $g(x,t)$ be two  bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb{R} \times (0,T)$, for some fixed $T>0$ such that $f(x,t)-g(y,t)$ attains a strict maximum at $(x_0,y_0,t_0)$. Now we consider a new function $$H(x,y,s,t):= f(x,t)-g(y,s)- \frac{|s-t|^2}{\epsilon} $$  in the domain $\overline{B_1}(x_0)\times \overline{B_1}(y_0)\times [t_0-h,t_0+h]^2$ for some $h>0$ and let $(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon,s_\epsilon,t_\epsilon)$ be a maximum point for $H$ in $\overline{B_1}(x_0)\times \overline{B_1}(y_0)\times [t_0-h,t_0+h]^2$. I need to show that $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon,s_\epsilon,t_\epsilon)=(x_0,y_0,t_0,t_0)$.

All I could understand is that the sequence $(x_\epsilon,y_\epsilon,s_\epsilon,t_\epsilon)$ is bounded and therefore there exists a convergent subsequence, but I don't understand how to identify the limit with $(x_0,y_0,t_0,t_0)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Omega=\overline{B}_1(x_0)\times\overline{B}_1(y_0)\times[t_0-h,t_0+h]^2$. Define $\phi(x,y,t)=f(x,t)-g(y,t)$ on $\overline{B}_1(x_0)\times\overline{B}_1(y_0)\times[t_0-h,t_0+h]$ and $G(y,s,t)=g(y,t)-g(y,s)$ on $\overline{B}_1(y_0)\times[t_0-h,t_0+h]^2$ and note that these two functions are continuous. Therefore there is some $M>0$ such that $|\phi(x,y,t)-G(y,s,t)|<M$ on $\Omega$ and for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there is some $\delta=\delta_n>0$ such that $|G(y,s,t)|<\frac{1}{n}$ whenever $|s-t|<\delta$.

Then on $\Omega$ we have
\begin{equation*}
H_\varepsilon(x,y,s,t)=\phi(x,y,t)-G(y,s,t)-\frac{(s-t)^2}{\varepsilon}.
\end{equation*}

**Claim**: $\frac{(s_\varepsilon-t_\varepsilon)^2}{\varepsilon}\leq 2M$ for all $\varepsilon$. Assume the contrary. Then there is some  $\varepsilon$ such that $\frac{(s_\varepsilon-t_\varepsilon)^2}{\varepsilon}>2M$ and therefore $H_\varepsilon(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)<-M<H_\varepsilon(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,t_0,t_0)$, contradicting the definition of the point $(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)$.

Now note that by construction, for $\varepsilon<1$, we have that
\begin{equation*}
H_1(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)>H_\varepsilon(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)\geq H_\varepsilon(x_0,y_0,t_0,t_0)=\phi(x_0,y_0,t_0).
\end{equation*}
On the other hand, from the previous claim, we know that $|s_\varepsilon-t_\varepsilon|\leq \sqrt{2M\varepsilon}$. So for an arbitrary $n\in\mathbb{N}$ for all $\varepsilon>0$ sufficiently small we have that $|s_\varepsilon-t_\varepsilon|<\delta$, implying that $|G(y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)|<\frac{1}{n}$.

Therefore,
\begin{equation*}
H_1(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)<\phi(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{(s_\varepsilon-t_\varepsilon)^2}{1}\leq\phi(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)+\frac{1}{n} \leq \phi(x_0,y_0,t_0)+\frac{1}{n}.
\end{equation*}

It follows that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0} H_1(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)=\phi(x_0,y_0,t_0)$.

Now let $\{(x_n,y_n,s_n,t_n)\}_n$ be an arbitrary convergent subsequence of the family $\{(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)\}_\varepsilon$ ( recall that we are in the compact domain $\Omega$). Let the limit of this subsequence be $(x',y',s',t')$. Due to the claim, note that we must have $s'=t'$.

$H_1$ is obviously a continuous function, so we obtain that
\begin{equation*}
\phi(x_0,y_0,t_0)=H_1(x',y',t',t')=\phi(x',y',t')
\end{equation*}

However, by assumption $(x_0,y_0,t_0)$ is the strict maximum of $\phi$, so we must have that $x'=x_0,y'=y_0,s'=t'=t_0$. Since the choice of the convergent subsequence was arbitrary and since $\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}(x_\varepsilon,y_\varepsilon,s_\varepsilon,t_\varepsilon)$ not existing (in a compact domain) implies the existence of two converging subsequences with different limits, we are done.